# Clojure sort-by with str and number? keyfunctions

Tags: clojure

Can anyone explain why `sort-by` is reacting like this with these keyfunctions?

```
user=> (sort-by number? [1 2 13 4 "s" 0 "a"])
("s" "a" 1 2 13 4 0)

user=> (sort-by str [1 2 3 4 "s" 0 "a"])
(0 1 2 3 4 "a" "s")
```

My idea is its dividing the args of the vector into strings and numbers? Is there anything more about what's happening here? 
And my second question does `sort-by` travel through every item of the vector and then returning the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`number?` returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the input is a number. `false` is apparently less than `true` for comparisons.

`str` returns a string whose value depends on the input. e.g. `(str 1) => "1"`. String comparison is somewhat complicated, but, in general, numerals are less than uppercase letters are less than lowercase letters and letters are sorted in alphabetical order.

I'm not sure exactly the behavior you're wanting, but it would seem that `(sort-by number? ...)` did indeed "divide the vector into strings and numbers" by giving you strings at the start of the list and numbers at the end.

If you're wanting to separate strings from numbers, use `(group-by number? ...)`

As for your second question, `sort-by` uses the `keyfn` for comparisons during a merge sort.

Comment: this is interesting, i didnt know that one can also use true false nil for comparisons:  `user=> (compare nil false)
-1` `user=> (compare true false) 
1
` What i couldn't get is the `number?`. `str` converts input into string and it is comparable, but `number?` returns true false, which is  like (nil < false < true), so it sorts all the strings (which are false) at the beginning, and then leaves the numbers unsorted! (which is not nice i think!)

Comment: Or leaves the numbers in the original order? Could one say that?

Comment: The docs for the underlying `Arrays.sort` say it *does* do a stable sort (i.e. equal elements will not be reordered). So I believe you can say that.